# AJAX Call is incrementing itself by +1 each time it's called

Tags: jquery, ajax, vb.net

I have a piece of JQuery AJAX that calls a VB.NET code-behind (class) that returns string data. It grabs some latest stats on a particular server. Now the code works, but the first time I press the refresh button data is returned and the alert "Refreshed" is shown on screen.

But if I press it again, the alert box "Refreshed" is shown twice, I click again three times! and  on and on, until the time-out kicks in.

It seems to be coming from the AJAX call and no where else. I'm at a loss at what could be calling this, I've tried deleting the data returned after success but no joy. Any ideas on what could be causing this or where to look?

```
function RefreshServer(btn,div,id,ip) {

$('#aRefresh'+id).html("<img src=images/refreshServer.gif border=0 align=absmiddle />");
$("#"+btn).click(function() {
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "Dashboard.aspx/refreshServerAJAX",
  timeout: 5000,
  data: "{'IP': '" + ip + "'}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(msg) {
    var substr = msg.d.split('%');
    $('#serverBox_mod'+id).html(" " +substr[0]);
    $('#serverBox_map'+id).html(" " +substr[1]);
    $('#serverBox_playing'+id).html(" " +substr[2] + "/" + substr[3]);
    $('#serverBox_img'+id).html("<img src=images/Maps/" + substr[4] + " height=80 width=120 border=0 style=margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px; />");
    $('#serverBox_title'+id).html(" " +substr[5]);
    $('#aRefresh'+id).html("Refresh");
    delete substr
    delete msg
    alert("Refreshed");  
  },
  error: function(msg) {
    $('#aRefresh'+id).html("Refresh");
    $('#serverBox_title'+id).html("Server didn't respond!, sorry about that. Please try again...");
  }
});
});  
}
```

Comment: Is this your actual code? You're missing a lot of semicolons.

Comment: So what exactly are you asking? Do you not want it to show multiple times?

Comment: @Jonathan M, Yes it is, sorry about that, I have edited.

Comment: @Farhan Ahmad The code should only be called once per button click. But the second time I click the button its called twice, third time, three times and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are binding the click event everytime you call the function. So it is making that many number of ajax calls to the server page. So If you want to keep the code structure as it is and fix it, I would unbind the click event already added and bind it again.

```
function RefreshServer(btn,div,id,ip) {

  $("#"+btn).unbind('click');
  $("#"+btn).click(function() {
     //your ajax code is here
  });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error doesn't seem to be in this particular area of code... but looking at it, it seems that you're setting the `click` handler for `$('#' + btn)` inside the `RefreshServer()` function. The reason that may be causing multiple AJAX calls on click normally is the simplest : you're attaching multiple event handlers on the same event.

Now, that can happen if you call the `RefreshServer()` function on the same `btn` instance multiple times, since that function assigns the handler. Is there any chance that that is happening in your code? I'm assuming that somehow, on each click, you're calling it somehow, therefore attaching another instance of an event handler to the button.

Comment: Hi @Richard, There is no other code called apart from the vb code, and that is only initialised by the AJAX call. Your second point certainly seems the most logical. But I am unsure on how to assign only one handler per button. (especially if that button is going to be clicked as many times as the user likes).

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb here, and suggest placing an `alert('foo');` call right after the opening brace when you declare `function RefreshServer()`. Then try to click the button. If this function is getting called on click, you're going to get the `alert()`, and that's going to be our culprit.

Comment: Thanks for your time Richard. @Shyju came up with a solution that works by unbinding the event. Looks like I know where my next area of study is going to be. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to call the ajax function once:

```
var ajaxLoading = false;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ajaxRequestor').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(!ajaxLoading) {
            ajaxLoading = true;
            $('#ajaxContentPlaceholder').load('/path/to/content.html', 
                function() { 
                    ajaxLoading = false;
                }
            );
        }
    });
});
```